# Can kafka producers supply data at quota rate in presence of replicas?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, kafka-python

I have a kafka producer belonging to client with clientid - "p1" and quota as 50 MBps.

Now I tested the performance of my producer using "bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh" and I was able to get throughput close to 50 MBps when writing to a partition without a replica.

I tried the same experiment on a partition with three replicas. But this time the throughput got reduced to 30 MBps.

My question is that shouldn't kafka allow the producer to still get a throughput of 50 MBps even in presence of replicas? There is nothing else running in the system, so I am not sure why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the `acks` config of producer? From you description it seems that `acks` is set to `all`, so producer waits untill the sent data will be replicated among three brokers which affects throughput. If you didn't change the `acks` try to set it to `0`, so producer will not wait for any acknowledgment from the server at all, just to see if it affects throughput.

Comment: I do want an ack from all (synchronous replication). My basic doubt is that since there is nothing else in the network, shouldn't kafka still allow the producer to get a throughput of 50 MBps.